# Combining options in find command

Tags: find

Using the `find` command is there a way to combine options:

i.e.

```
find . -type fd -name "somefile"
```

Although `-type` ignores the second option; I'm looking to find only files or directories.

Comment: Note that `f` is for _regular files_, not _files_ (other types are files as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot combine characters after `-type` (unless you have a different find than I have). You have to do something like:

```
 find .  \( -type f -o -type d \) -name "somefile"
```

On my system:

```
 $ find .  -type fd -name "somefile"
 find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter
```

That messages comes from the function `insert_type()` at line 2601 in 
[findutils-4.4.2](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/findutils/findutils-4.4.2.tar.gz) `find/parser.c`. It just takes the first character, older/other versions of `find` did IIRC not even warn if there were multiple characters after `-type`.

Comment: do you know why the find command in particular doesn't allow the combining of options?

Comment: @NedSchneebly `fd` would be the combination of an argument to option `-type` not an option itself. It is just programmed that way `find`'s option handling with single dashes but long option names is IMHO strange anyway. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question during my studies. Two years into the future from your question and someone has added the feature into `find` and it's been integrated into Debian and from there Ubuntu. Doesn't appear to be integrated into Red Hat yet (sad) but may be in Fedora (haven't checked).

```
find / -mmin -300 -type f -o -type d -exec ls -l {} \;
```

OR

```
find / -mmin -300 -type f,d -exec file {} \;
```

See [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-findutils/2016-02/msg00025.html) for details.